# R: How to print only the first 5 TRUE conditions in a loop without limiting the range of the loop

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of numbers.

```
x <- c(10,12,5,23,40,27,11,4,7,25,21,7,99,45,2,10)
```

I want to print the first 5 numbers greater than 20 using an if condition inside a for loop reason being this is a simple reproducible example and the actual scenario requires if conditions inside for loops. Is there a way of getting the first 5 numbers greater than 20 without limiting the range? The way to find all the numbers greater than 20 would be something like this

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
if(x[i]>20){
print(x[i])
}
}
```

The problem can be also looked upon as limiting the print statement to the first 5 instances.
Can someone help?
Please note that the range of the for loop can not be limited to arrive at a solution.

Required answer would be

```
23,40,27,25,21
```

Using for loop, if condition and print statement/cat/writeLines is a must

Comment: Is it OK to *exit the loop* when there are 5 hits or is something else happening in the not simplified loop which need to be done for the rest.

Comment: Preferably the use case should successfully go through the entire list of values and return the first 5 that satisfies the condition. It should also return the TRUE conditions even when the condition doesn't evaluate into 5 TRUE conditions. For example the logic should be for first 5 but even if we get just 2 conditions instead of a maximum of 5 then those 2 should be printed. Regarding your question, I assume in this use case iterating through the entire loop when first 5 condition has been met would be a waste of memory?

Comment: Thanks. Ok but then a solution would also be possible which is already *limiting the range* of the `for` loop.

Comment: I've thought about it too. Can you tell me what exactly you're thinking about?

Comment: For example: `for(i in which(cumsum(x > 20) <= 5)) {...`

Comment: Got it! But I don't think this would be of use here.

Answer (score 3):

Will this work:

```
x[x > 20][1:5]
[1] 23 40 27 25 21
```

Using for loop:

```
v <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i] > 20){
    v <- c(v,x[i])
  }  
  if(length(v) == 5){
    print(v)
    break
  }
}
[1] 23 40 27 25 21
```

Comment: This’ll yield wonky results if there are fewer than 5 results.

Comment: This works in this instance. But the use case requires using a print statement inside the if condition inside for loops. I've tried to put it across as simply as possible!

Comment: @Nil_07, have added `for` loop, please check if that works

Comment: I'll try this out for my case @Karthik S. Meanwhile your solution and GKi's solution below looks similar and helpful.

Comment: @Nil_07, it's basically creating an empty vector and populating it as per our condition(s).

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out that *limiting the range of the for loop* is allowed, this could be done with `cumsum(x > 20) <= 5`:

```
for(i in seq_len(match(5, cumsum(x > 20), length(x)))) {
  if(x[i] > 20) {
    print(x[i])
  }
}
#[1] 23
#[1] 40
#[1] 27
#[1] 25
#[1] 21
```

Or add a counter:

Variant which will break after 5 hits (thanks to @sindri-baldur):

```
n <- 0L
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i]>20) {
    print(x[i])
    n <- n+1L
    if(n == 5L) break
  }
}
```

Variant which will make the full loop.

```
n <- 0L
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i]>20 & n<5) {
    n <- n+1L
    print(x[i])
  }
}
```

To get the first 5 you can use `head`:

```
head(x[x > 20], 5)
#[1] 23 40 27 25 21
```

Note that this will also work in cases where there are *less than 5 hits*. Then it will return the number of hits. E.g. try it with:

```
x <- c(10,12,5,23,40,27,11,4,7,25,2,7,9,4,2,10)
```

Comment: I would add instead `if (n == 5L) break` in case `x` is very long.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I don't know that else will happen in the *not simplified* loop. And in the question i can read *without limiting the range*. But maybe `break` could be used but it will *limit* the range.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thanks for the hint. Actually it turns out that *limiting the range* is allowed. So I add a variant with your suggestion.